# Array php foreach looping

Tags: foreach

consider the following array

```
$arr1=array('a'=>2,'b'=>22,'c'=>4,'d'=>10)
```

Now,for

```
print_r(array_keys($arr1));
```

output is

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d )
```

Fine because return type of array_keys is array.
Even `echo array_keys($arr1);` gives `Array` as output.

But,for

```
foreach(array_keys($arr1) as $key)
 {
     echo $key.'<br/>';
  }
```

output is `abcd` Can someone explain how `foreach` is working here as i was expecting the following output

```
[a] => 2 
[b] => 22 
[c] => 4 
[d] => 10
```

Do not want a better code so as to display my expected output.Just want to know how foreach is looping in this case.

Comment: Why should the `foreach` lead to this output when all you have in your `echo` is `$key` and a HTML line break? You can get key **and** value in a loop with `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` and then output both. Might be a little bit too much, but maybe have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

`array_keys($arr1)` gets the array keys so it's looping throught ["a","b","c","d"].

furthermore your output for `print_r(array_keys($arr1))` is wrong since it outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
```

not what you have written

i quote you :

> Now,for
>
> print_r(array_keys($arr1)); output is
>
> Array ( [a] => 2 [b] => 22 [c] => 4 [d] => 10 )

**which is not correct**

Comment: oops...copy-paste mistake...!!

Comment: `array_keys($arr1)` does get it looping through a,b,c,d and assign them to $ key through subsequent loops but sud it not assign [0]=>'a',[1]=>'b',[2]=>'c' and [3]=>'d' since the output of array_keys is array

Comment: all arrays are "assiociative" in PHP , wether the index is a integer or a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax :

```
<?php
foreach($arr1 as $key => $values) {
        echo $key . "=>" . $values;
    }
?>
```

Comment: "HOW the output came" is the issue here,rather than "what sud be the code to get the output"..anyways,thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

`foreach(array_keys($arr1) as $key)` iterates over the keys of `$arr1`, assigning the current key to `$key` in turn. 'current' means the key of the current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's simply how [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php) works. Since `array_keys` returns the keys ("a","b",...) of your array `array_keys($arr1)` is the same as `Array("a","b","c","d")`, which is

```
Array( [0] => "a", [1] => "b", ... )
```

Since you want to iterate over both keys and values in your array you should simply use

```
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
    echo "[{$key}] = {$value}<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function array_keys returns all the keys of your array. To get what you wanted, you should use something like this

```
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . "=>" . $value;
}
```